# While trying to connect through ansible hosts.yaml getting this error

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, ansible

I am operating from MAC PRO, i installed terraform and ansible , launched few instances using terraform script but while trying to install using ansible getting following issue, unable to ping those machines

I edited the hosts.yaml file with the proper IP ( ec2-IP.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com) but while run the command

```
ansible -i hosts.yml all -m ping
```

getting this error

```
[WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host ip-172-31-37-15.us-east-2.compute.internal: Failed to
connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname ip-172-31-37-15.us-east-2.compute.internal: nodename nor
servname provided, or not known
[WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host ip-172-31-34-231.us-east-2.compute.internal: Failed to
connect to the host via ssh: ssh: Could not resolve hostname ip-172-31-34-231.us-east-2.compute.internal: nodename nor
servname provided, or not known
[WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host ec2-54-202-214-68.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:
Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-54-202-214-68.us-
west-2.compute.amazonaws.com,54.202.214.68' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.  ec2-user@ec2-54-202-214-68.us-
west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
ec2-54-202-214-68.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Data could not be sent to remote host \"ec2-54-202-214-68.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh: ec2-user@ec2-54-202-214-68.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
ip-172-31-37-15.us-east-2.compute.internal | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "
}
ip-172-31-34-231.us-east-2.compute.internal | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "
```

Answer (score 0):

Create passwordless ssh from ansible server for remote servers first. After that you can run command.
ansible -i hosts.yml all -m ping

Also, be sure that you have remote_user in any of the file ansible.cfg/inventory file along with remoteuser IP.

you should use vars if your IPs are private

```
cat inventory file
[server]
172.31.37.15 ansible_user=root

[server:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args=' -o ProxyCommand="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -W %h:%p stack@public_IP"'
```